# how to ExpansionTile set true or false without taping on it in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to change state of ExpansionTile with floating action button...

while onpressed of FAB...

expansionTile of selected index should be changed to Expanded <-> Collapse

is It possible?

my main concept is to create a single selected expansionTile without using any other widget..only one tile should b expanded at a time...

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    'A': 200,
    'B': 300,
    'C': 030,
    'D': 500,
    'E': 390,
    'F': 300,
  };


  int? expandIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: map.keys.toList().length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text(map.keys.toList()[index]),
                      children: [
                        Row(children: [
                          Text(map.values.toList()[index].toString())
                        ],)
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            int number=Random().nextInt(5);
            //5th expansionTile should be changed from true to false or visa varsa
            

          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check `ExpansionTileController`